# How to perform heroku-like deployment on shared hosting?

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment

For our production server we use shared hosting. Until now, we were using FTP system to manually upload changes.

I am looking for a technique that lets me use git to push only changes from development to production server.

For my private projects I was using GitHub as development remote and Heroku as production remote. I am looking for something that can do similar thing without using Heroku itself. (note that we use shared hosting). I want to have two remotes, development (to development server) and production remote (from development server to production server). **Idea is to push from development server to production server using git.**

Projects are mostly written in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use dokku and it's usage is explained right here: https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/dokku-tutorial-digital-ocean/

Moreover, you can use ansible and it is far more extensible.